# Video not displaying on iOS-to-iOS WebRTC call despite working encryption and decryption

Tags: ios, swift, encryption, webview, webrtc

No video on screen while calling from iOS to iOS via encrypted channel with WebRTC.

There is an application that is running on Android and iOS and has WebRTC calls. On Android it has voice and video encrypted using WebView with custom JS code, while on iOS it has WebRTC library from Google with added ability to use encryption (by using [FrameEncryptorInterface](https://webrtc.googlesource.com/src/+/refs/heads/main/api/crypto/frame_encryptor_interface.h) and [FrameDecryptorInterface](https://webrtc.googlesource.com/src/+/refs/heads/main/api/crypto/frame_decryptor_interface.h) as a base).

Situation:

- Android with Android: encryption and decryption work fine, as well as actual video on a screen and sound
- Android with iOS works fine, as well as actual video on the screen and sound
- iOS with iOS have working encryption and decryption for both audio and video, have working sound, but not working video on a screen. Shows just a blank screen for incoming video. However, as I said, encryption and decryption work fine (I see logs).

There are no crashes, looks like everything should work, but iOS to iOS video is still not showing on the screen.

Since there are so many components in different languages that are in use (Typescript, Haskell, Swift), I provide the main part of them:

Android ([source](https://github.com/simplex-chat/simplex-chat/blob/stable/packages/simplex-chat-webrtc/src/call.ts)):

```js
function callCryptoFunction(): CallCrypto {
  const initialPlainTextRequired = {
    key: 10,
    delta: 3,
    empty: 1,
  }

  const IV_LENGTH = 12

  function encryptFrame(key: CryptoKey): (frame: RTCEncodedVideoFrame, controller: TransformStreamDefaultController) => Promise<void> {
    return async (frame, controller) => {
      const data = new Uint8Array(frame.data)
      const n = initialPlainTextRequired[frame.type] || 1
      const iv = randomIV()
      const initial = data.subarray(0, n)
      const plaintext = data.subarray(n, data.byteLength)
      try {
        const ciphertext = plaintext.length
          ? new Uint8Array(await crypto.subtle.encrypt({name: "AES-GCM", iv: iv.buffer}, key, plaintext))
          : new Uint8Array(0)
        frame.data = concatN(initial, ciphertext, iv).buffer
        controller.enqueue(frame)
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(`encryption error ${e}`)
        throw e
      }
    }
  }

  function decryptFrame(key: CryptoKey): (frame: RTCEncodedVideoFrame, controller: TransformStreamDefaultController) => Promise<void> {
    return async (frame, controller) => {
      const data = new Uint8Array(frame.data)
      const n = initialPlainTextRequired[frame.type] || 1
      const initial = data.subarray(0, n)
      const ciphertext = data.subarray(n, data.byteLength - IV_LENGTH)
      const iv = data.subarray(data.byteLength - IV_LENGTH, data.byteLength)
      try {
        const plaintext = ciphertext.length
          ? new Uint8Array(await crypto.subtle.decrypt({name: "AES-GCM", iv}, key, ciphertext))
          : new Uint8Array(0)
        frame.data = concatN(initial, plaintext).buffer
        controller.enqueue(frame)
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(`decryption error ${e}`)
        throw e
      }
    }
  }

  function decodeAesKey(aesKey: string): Promise<CryptoKey> {
    const keyData = callCrypto.decodeBase64url(callCrypto.encodeAscii(aesKey))
    return crypto.subtle.importKey("raw", keyData!, {name: "AES-GCM", length: 256}, true, ["encrypt", "decrypt"])
  }

  function randomIV() {
    return crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint8Array(IV_LENGTH))
  }
//...

}
```

iOS native WebRTC lib additions ([source](https://github.com/simplex-chat/WebRTC/blob/latest/patches/0001-Frame-encryption-in-non-native-API.patch)):

// DECRYPTOR

```objectivec
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "RTCFrameDecryptor+Private.h"
#import "base/RTCLogging.h"

#include "rtc_base/checks.h"
#include "api/crypto/frame_decryptor_interface.h"
#include "RTCRtpReceiver+Private.h"

namespace webrtc {
RTCFrameDecryptorAdapter::RTCFrameDecryptorAdapter(RTC_OBJC_TYPE(RTCFrameDecryptor) * decryptor, size_t sizeChange) {
  RTC_CHECK(decryptor);
  decryptor_ = decryptor;
  sizeChange_ = sizeChange;
}

RTCFrameDecryptorAdapter::Result RTCFrameDecryptorAdapter::Decrypt(
    cricket::MediaType media_type,
    const std::vector<uint32_t>& csrcs,
    rtc::ArrayView<const uint8_t> additional_data,
    rtc::ArrayView<const uint8_t> encrypted_frame,
    rtc::ArrayView<uint8_t> frame) {
  RTC_OBJC_TYPE(RTCFrameDecryptor) *decryptor = decryptor_;
  NSData *encrypted = [NSData dataWithBytes: encrypted_frame.data() length: encrypted_frame.size()];
  NSData *decrypted = [decryptor.delegate frameDecryptor:decryptor mediaType:[RTC_OBJC_TYPE(RTCRtpReceiver) mediaTypeForNativeMediaType: media_type] withFrame:encrypted];
  if (decrypted) {
    const char * decryptedBytes = (const char *)[decrypted bytes];
    NSUInteger size = [decrypted length];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {
      frame[i] = decryptedBytes[i];
    }
    return Result(Status::kOk, size);
  } else {
    return Result(Status::kFailedToDecrypt, 0);
  }

}

size_t RTCFrameDecryptorAdapter::GetMaxPlaintextByteSize(
  cricket::MediaType media_type,
  size_t encrypted_frame_size) {
  return encrypted_frame_size + sizeChange_;
}
}  // namespace webrtc


@implementation RTC_OBJC_TYPE (RTCFrameDecryptor) {
  rtc::scoped_refptr<webrtc::FrameDecryptorInterface> _nativeFrameDecryptor;
}

@synthesize delegate = _delegate;
@synthesize nativeFrameDecryptor = _nativeFrameDecryptor;

- (NSString *)description {
  return [NSString
      stringWithFormat:@"RTC_OBJC_TYPE(RTCFrameDecryptor)"];
}

- (void)dealloc {
  _nativeFrameDecryptor = nullptr;
}

- (BOOL)isEqual:(id)object {
  if (self == object) {
    return YES;
  }
  if (object == nil) {
    return NO;
  }
  if (![object isMemberOfClass:[self class]]) {
    return NO;
  }
  RTC_OBJC_TYPE(RTCFrameDecryptor) *decryptor = (RTC_OBJC_TYPE(RTCFrameDecryptor) *)object;
  return _nativeFrameDecryptor == decryptor.nativeFrameDecryptor;
}

- (NSUInteger)hash {
  return (NSUInteger)_nativeFrameDecryptor.get();
}

- (instancetype)initWithSizeChange:(int)sizeChange {
  if (self = [super init]) {
    RTCLogInfo(@"RTC_OBJC_TYPE(RTCFrameDecryptor)(%p): created decryptor: %@", self, self.description);
    _nativeFrameDecryptor = new webrtc::RTCFrameDecryptorAdapter(self, sizeChange);
  }
  return self;
}

@end
```

// ENCRYPTOR

```objectivec
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "RTCFrameEncryptor+Private.h"
#import "base/RTCLogging.h"

#include "rtc_base/checks.h"
#include "api/crypto/frame_encryptor_interface.h"
#include "RTCRtpReceiver+Private.h"

namespace webrtc {
RTCFrameEncryptorAdapter::RTCFrameEncryptorAdapter(RTC_OBJC_TYPE(RTCFrameEncryptor) * encryptor, size_t sizeChange) {
  RTC_CHECK(encryptor);
  encryptor_ = encryptor;
  sizeChange_ = sizeChange;
}

int RTCFrameEncryptorAdapter::Encrypt(
    cricket::MediaType media_type,
    uint32_t ssrc,
    rtc::ArrayView<const uint8_t> additional_data,
    rtc::ArrayView<const uint8_t> frame,
    rtc::ArrayView<uint8_t> encrypted_frame,
    size_t* bytes_written) {
  RTC_OBJC_TYPE(RTCFrameEncryptor) *encryptor = encryptor_;
  NSData *unencrypted = [NSData dataWithBytes: frame.data() length: frame.size()];
  NSData *encrypted = [encryptor.delegate frameEncryptor:encryptor mediaType:[RTC_OBJC_TYPE(RTCRtpReceiver) mediaTypeForNativeMediaType: media_type] withFrame:unencrypted];
  if (encrypted) {
    const char *encryptedBytes = (const char *)[encrypted bytes];
    NSUInteger size = [encrypted length];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {
      encrypted_frame[i] = encryptedBytes[i];
    }
    *bytes_written = size;
    return 0;
  } else {
    return 1;
  }

}

size_t RTCFrameEncryptorAdapter::GetMaxCiphertextByteSize(
  cricket::MediaType media_type,
  size_t frame_size) {
  return frame_size + sizeChange_;
}
}  // namespace webrtc


@implementation RTC_OBJC_TYPE (RTCFrameEncryptor) {
  rtc::scoped_refptr<webrtc::FrameEncryptorInterface> _nativeFrameEncryptor;
}

@synthesize delegate = _delegate;
@synthesize nativeFrameEncryptor = _nativeFrameEncryptor;

- (NSString *)description {
  return [NSString
      stringWithFormat:@"RTC_OBJC_TYPE(RTCFrameEncryptor)"];
}

- (void)dealloc {
  _nativeFrameEncryptor = nullptr;
}

- (BOOL)isEqual:(id)object {
  if (self == object) {
    return YES;
  }
  if (object == nil) {
    return NO;
  }
  if (![object isMemberOfClass:[self class]]) {
    return NO;
  }
  RTC_OBJC_TYPE(RTCFrameEncryptor) *encryptor = (RTC_OBJC_TYPE(RTCFrameEncryptor) *)object;
  return _nativeFrameEncryptor == encryptor.nativeFrameEncryptor;
}

- (NSUInteger)hash {
  return (NSUInteger)_nativeFrameEncryptor.get();
}

- (instancetype)initWithSizeChange:(int)sizeChange {
  if (self = [super init]) {
    RTCLogInfo(@"RTC_OBJC_TYPE(RTCFrameEncryptor)(%p): created encryptor: %@", self, self.description);
    _nativeFrameEncryptor = new webrtc::RTCFrameEncryptorAdapter(self, sizeChange);
  }
  return self;
}

@end
```

iOS Swift ([source](https://github.com/simplex-chat/simplex-chat/blob/stable/apps/ios/Shared/Views/Call/WebRTCClient.swift)):

```swift
// WebRTCClient.swift

private static let ivTagBytes: Int = 28 // iv + tag, 12 + 16

let encryptor = RTCFrameEncryptor.init(sizeChange: Int32(WebRTCClient.ivTagBytes))
let decryptor = RTCFrameDecryptor.init(sizeChange: -Int32(WebRTCClient.ivTagBytes))

    func frameDecryptor(_ decryptor: RTCFrameDecryptor, mediaType: RTCRtpMediaType, withFrame encrypted: Data) -> Data? {
        guard encrypted.count > 0 else { return nil }
        if var key: [CChar] = activeCall.wrappedValue?.aesKey?.cString(using: .utf8),
           let pointer: UnsafeMutableRawPointer = malloc(encrypted.count) {
            memcpy(pointer, (encrypted as NSData).bytes, encrypted.count)
            let isKeyFrame = encrypted[0] & 1 == 0
            let clearTextBytesSize = mediaType.rawValue == 0 ? 1 : isKeyFrame ? 10 : 3
            logCrypto("decrypt", chat_decrypt_media(&key, pointer.advanced(by: clearTextBytesSize), Int32(encrypted.count - clearTextBytesSize)))
            return Data(bytes: pointer, count: encrypted.count - WebRTCClient.ivTagBytes)
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }

    func frameEncryptor(_ encryptor: RTCFrameEncryptor, mediaType: RTCRtpMediaType, withFrame unencrypted: Data) -> Data? {
        guard unencrypted.count > 0 else { return nil }
        if var key: [CChar] = activeCall.wrappedValue?.aesKey?.cString(using: .utf8),
           let pointer: UnsafeMutableRawPointer = malloc(unencrypted.count + WebRTCClient.ivTagBytes) {
            memcpy(pointer, (unencrypted as NSData).bytes, unencrypted.count)
            let isKeyFrame = unencrypted[0] & 1 == 0
            let clearTextBytesSize = mediaType.rawValue == 0 ? 1 : isKeyFrame ? 10 : 3
            logCrypto("encrypt", chat_encrypt_media(&key, pointer.advanced(by: clearTextBytesSize), Int32(unencrypted.count + WebRTCClient.ivTagBytes - clearTextBytesSize)))
            return Data(bytes: pointer, count: unencrypted.count + WebRTCClient.ivTagBytes)
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
```

iOS encryption/decryption part ([source](https://github.com/simplex-chat/simplex-chat/blob/stable/src/Simplex/Chat/Mobile/WebRTC.hs)):

```hs
chatEncryptMedia :: ByteString -> ByteString -> ExceptT String IO ByteString
chatEncryptMedia keyStr frame = do
  len <- checkFrameLen frame
  key <- decodeKey keyStr
  iv <- liftIO C.randomGCMIV
  (tag, frame') <- withExceptT show $ C.encryptAESNoPad key iv $ B.take len frame
  pure $ frame' <> BA.convert (C.unAuthTag tag) <> C.unGCMIV iv

chatDecryptMedia :: ByteString -> ByteString -> ExceptT String IO ByteString
chatDecryptMedia keyStr frame = do
  len <- checkFrameLen frame
  key <- decodeKey keyStr
  let (frame', rest) = B.splitAt len frame
      (tag, iv) = B.splitAt C.authTagSize rest
      authTag = C.AuthTag $ AES.AuthTag $ BA.convert tag
  withExceptT show $ do
    iv' <- liftEither $ C.gcmIV iv
    frame'' <- C.decryptAESNoPad key iv' frame' authTag
    pure $ frame'' <> framePad

checkFrameLen :: ByteString -> ExceptT String IO Int
checkFrameLen frame = do
  let len = B.length frame - reservedSize
  when (len < 0) $ throwError "frame has no [reserved space for] IV and/or auth tag"
  pure len
{-# INLINE checkFrameLen #-}

decodeKey :: ByteString -> ExceptT String IO C.Key
decodeKey = liftEither . bimap ("invalid key: " <>) C.Key . U.decode
{-# INLINE decodeKey #-}

reservedSize :: Int
reservedSize = C.authTagSize + C.gcmIVSize

framePad :: ByteString
framePad = B.replicate reservedSize 0
```

Please, click on "source" link to view all code if you need more context.

Do you have an idea why there is no video on screen via iOS-to-iOS call?

I tried:

- to place encryptor and decryptor attaching action to specific sender and receiver into different states of WebRTC connections (like connected, connection, checking, etc)
- to change `sizeChange` parameter but app crashes or does nothing after that (depends on increasing or decreasing the value)
- to compare encrypted and decrypted byte array at both ends on Android-iOS and iOS-iOS and the result was **the same**. I mean the result was like it should be
- to comment lines

```swift
logCrypto("decrypt", chat_decrypt_media(&key, pointer.advanced(by: clearTextBytesSize), Int32(encrypted.count - clearTextBytesSize)))
```

and

```swift
logCrypto("encrypt", chat_encrypt_media(&key, pointer.advanced(by: clearTextBytesSize), Int32(unencrypted.count + WebRTCClient.ivTagBytes - clearTextBytesSize)))
```

After that everything works ok but there is no encryption, of course, in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was just this one line. For some reason, even when calling between iOS devices, I have to specify preferredCodec in RTCDefaultVideoDecoderFactory. Like this:

```swift
private static let factory: RTCPeerConnectionFactory = {
        RTCInitializeSSL()
        let videoEncoderFactory = RTCDefaultVideoEncoderFactory()
        let videoDecoderFactory = RTCDefaultVideoDecoderFactory()
+        videoEncoderFactory.preferredCodec = RTCVideoCodecInfo(name: kRTCVp8CodecName)
        return RTCPeerConnectionFactory(encoderFactory: videoEncoderFactory, decoderFactory: videoDecoderFactory)
    }()
```

Now everything is working fine.